# illegal instruction: PRINTN

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to build a program that check if ax is divisible by 7 with no remainder.

```
org 100h   
  mov ax,14
  mov cl,7
  div cl
  cmp ah,0
  je positive
    PRINTN   "The number has a remainder"
  jmp finish
 positive:
    PRINTN   "The number has no remainder"
 finish:
     PRINTN   "After comparison"  
mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret
```

Assembling this program gives me these errors:

```
(7) illegal instruction: PRINTN   "The number has a remainder" or wrong parameters.
(10) illegal instruction: PRINTN   "The number has no remainder" or wrong parameters.
(12) illegal instruction: PRINTN   "After comparison" or wrong parameters.
```

Comment: `PRINTN` isn't an x86 instruction, and you didn't include any macro file that would define it.  If it's a function, you need to pass it args and `call` it.

Comment: I see it calls the BIOS read key press function. But which assembler/toolset are you using?
It looks like you are missing the subroutine {{{PRINTN}}}. Perhaps you need to pull in some extra file that defines it?

Comment: how can i print a string in assembler x86?

Comment: @OphirBraude That depends on what operating system you are programming for.  For DOS, check out [INT 21h/AH=09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm).  This allows you to write a `$`-terminated string to standard output.

Comment: That said, where did you get `PRINTN` from?

Comment: http://jbwyatt.com/253/emu/asm_tutorial_05.html

Answer (score 2):

To use any of the functions in emu8086.inc you should have the following line at the beginning of your source file:

***include 'emu8086.inc'***

```
org 100h    
  include 'emu8086.inc'
  mov ax,14
  mov cl,7
  div cl
  cmp ah,0
  je positive
    PRINTN   "The number has a remainder"
  jmp finish
 positive:
    PRINTN   "The number has no remainder"
 finish:
     PRINTN   "After comparison"  
mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret
```

Have a look at this website for more reference:
https://jbwyatt.com/253/emu/asm_tutorial_05.html